# Why do some aerosol particles never settle down?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Particles and liquid droplets below the size of 1 micrometer usually never settle down easily, and as their size decreases, it takes longer for them to settle down. Why is it like that? Does Stoke's law have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As aerosol particles get smaller, their small inertia makes them susceptible to molecular collisions with the fluid particles surrounding them—leading to the aerosol particles undergoing Brownian motion as well as any other physical effects you'd expect (like gravitational acceleration, quasi-Stokes drag, etc.) When particles are "sufficiently" small, the effects causing Brownian motion dominate, leading the aerosol particle to mostly wander around in place rather than accelerate downwards.

However—if this was the whole picture, then any aerosol would (on average) eventually settle after a sufficiently long period of time. However, in most settings, we also find *macroscale* fluctuations in the fluid as a result of external movement or random density changes, which cause short macroscale flows that "lift" the particle up and make settling even more difficult.

Comment: So why does the gravitational force no longer becomes dominant?

Comment: The force the particle feels from gravity is proportional to its mass, whereas the force it feels as a result of collisions with its neighbors is largely independent of it. Therefore, as the mass of the particle gets smaller, the gravitational force also becomes smaller, until it becomes small enough to neglect compared to the other forces the particle is subjected to.

Comment: I am considering liquid droplets. Does reducing size of the droplet drastically reduce its mass though?

Comment: which equation are you quoting? Mass is proportional to 3rd power of radius, right?

Comment: Apologies, I misspoke; yes, mass is proportional to the third power of the droplet radius assuming constant density, which makes the mass of the droplet particularly sensitive to the length scale of the size of the droplet. So when the radius of the droplet is halved, the mass goes down by factor of 8.

Comment: now i think i got a gist of it. Thank you so much for the help. It means a lot.